# programatically set auto refresh on a SSRS report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, windows-server-2008

I'm developing a dashboard report in SSRS 2008R2, and I need to refresh it ever 1 minute or so, Is there's any way to do that other than pressing the refresh button on the browser!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set AutoRefresh property of the report to whatever no. of seconds you want the report to be refreshed.